# JAVA Wrong output

Tags: java

I cannot find the mistake in my code.

> Write a method RandomWalkers.java that takes two integer arguments N and T. In each of T independent experiments, simulate a random walk of N steps and compute the squared distance. Output the mean squared distance (the average of the T squared distances).
>
> ```
> % java RandomWalkers 100 10000
> mean squared distance = 101.446
>
> % java RandomWalkers 100 10000
> mean squared distance = 99.1674
>
> % java RandomWalkers 200 1000
> mean squared distance = 195.75
>
> % java RandomWalkers 400 2000
> mean squared distance = 383.12
>
> % java RandomWalkers 800 5000
> mean squared distance = 811.8264
>
> % java RandomWalkers 1600 100000
> mean squared distance = 1600.13064
> ```
>
> Use RandomWalkers to formulate a hypothesis as to how the mean >squared distance grows as a function of N. Use a variety of values
> for T (as shown above) for testing the program, but for this analysis, use T = 100,000 trials to get a sufficiently accurate estimate.

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomWalkers{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N=input.nextInt();
        int T=input.nextInt();
        double direction;
        double output=0;
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            int x=0;
            int y=0;
          for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            direction=Math.random()*3;
            switch((int)direction){
                case 0:
                y++; 
                break;
                case 1:
                x++;
                break; 
                case 2:
                y--;
                break;
                case 3:
                x--;
                break;
            }
           }
             output+=((x*x)+(y*y));
          }
        System.out.println("mean squared distance = "+ output/T);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what's wrong about your input (or if the examples you show are part of the requirements or the output of your code). One thing I see is that your code tries to read the values from standard input using a `Scanner`, whereas the requirements seem to suggest that they are arguments to your program (i.e. passed in through `args`).

Comment: Perhaps you could point us to the textbook or course in question, so that we may better understand the context.